# add styles to generated checkstyle report

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I generate checkstyle report using maven like this

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/checkstyle/checkstyle_output</outputDirectory>
                <configLocation>src/main/config/sun-checks.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But the problem is that the result `.html` page does not have any styles at all. It looks like this

[image]

How to add styles?

Comment: Note that the ability to generate an HTML report is a feature of the [Maven Checkstyle Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/), not of Checkstyle. The Maven plugin transforms the Checkstyle XML report into HTML. Just to let you know.